# Multi-line Markdown comments in Emacs

Tags: emacs, comments, markdown

How can I select a couple of Markdown lines in Emacs to have a multi-line comment? Currently, if I use `Alt-;` I will get:

```
<!-- line 1 -->
<!-- line 2 -->
```

But I would like to get:

```
<!-- line 1
line 2 -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest built-in commenting style to what you want seems to be `multi-line`, though it adds some additional characters:

```
<!-- line 1
 !-- line 2 -->
```

You can partially get rid of the `!--` by setting `comment-continue`, but on my machine the empty string doesn't seem to work. This is the best I was able to come up with:

```
(setf comment-continue " ")
(setf comment-style 'multi-line)
```

and then use `M-;` as usual:

```
<!-- line 1
  line 2 -->
```